# Isapi ReWrite: How can I match a part of a url?

Tags: url-rewriting, isapi-rewrite

we are moving website platforms. The old site has some url rewriting built into it, so the urls look like "/product-name-here-1.aspx". I need to get the id out of this url using Isapi-Rewrite syntax.

I've got a map file that takes the id and redirect to the page on the new platform.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it should be something like this:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^.+-(\d+)\.aspx$ ...
```

Not sure what the right part of the rule should be as you haven't specified that.